# Browser download js file in a different directory

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend

I'm building an app using Go on backend and React on frontend.
I'm gonna state my problem first:

**Problem**

I requested a URL on browser http://localhost:3000/story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512 (client side routing)
and I'm expecting all my js files be downloaded to `js` folder instead of `story/js` as displayed in the screenshot below.

[image]

On the backend I can see that the frontend is requesting files from that /story/js/* URL while its expected to request /js/*

```
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:55:59 | 304 | 14.378108182s |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/story/js/bundle.js.map"
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:55:59 | 200 | 17.669951527s |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/story/js/main.chunk.js"
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:56:00 | 200 | 29.195773528s |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/story/js/0.chunk.js"
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:56:00 | 308 |      68.265µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/sockjs-node"
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:56:00 | 304 |     134.182µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/story/js/0.chunk.js.map"
[GIN] 2021/07/26 - 21:56:00 | 304 |     148.597µs |       127.0.0.1 | GET      "/story/js/main.chunk.js.map"
```

**My Setup:**

I first compile my React files to a local directory, and have the Go backend serve the static file. But I'm using gin as my web framework, and it doesn't support dynamic URL for static file serving. e.g.: for the URL in question: http://localhost:3000/story/. So I did some hacking on the backend to map those dynamic URL to static URL.

**My Reasoning**

I can see that my React index.html has the following:

```
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script><script src="js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
```

So I doubt that the `index.html` was first downloaded to the `story/` directory in the browser in the first place. And the question to ask is: what caused the browser to save an index.html file to a different directory? I'd really appreciate if anyone knows the answer to that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured that the reason why I downloaded my file to that weird folder:
The URL I had http://localhost:3000/story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512 was client side routing. So when I requested the URL in the browser, it looked for a file story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512 in my directory.

It's the same problem stated in
[React - Serving Apps with Client-Side Routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)

And my backend handled it in a way to return files for `http://localhost:3000/story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512`, and what ended up showing was the `index.html` file was saved as `story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512`

I used Chrome to show the file structure, and it's displayed more straightforward this way:
Requesting `http://localhost:3000/story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512`, see the file `story/5fdeb38eebbe1593ce53a512` is actually my `index.html`
[image]

Requesting `http://localhost:3000`
[image]

**Solution**
The [React link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) I posted above mentioned solutions using either Apache HTTP Server or Tomcat to map certain URL to static file directory.